# MS Graph API for user entities throws "Complex query on property identities is not supported"

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using Azure B2C with built-in "sign up and sign in" user flow. When a user has registered an account is created as a local account. Email is only available in `Identities` property, `mail` and `OtherMails` properties are empty.

Now I need to search for users by email and some other property using MS graph API `User` endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=identities/any(id:id/issuer+eq+'mytenant.onmicrosoft.com'+and+id/issuerAssignedId+eq+'user@email.com')+and+creationType+eq+'LocalAccount'
```

This HTTP request will generate the below exception.

> "Complex query on property identities is not supported.

Exception appeared because I'm searching email using `identities` property and some other property. Is there any way to search users via an email and other properties (name, surname etc..) - If it's not possible is there a way to force user flow to store email in `mail` property?

Answer (score 0):

> The error occurred as **direct filtering** on the `identities` property is not supported for **complex** queries.

I registered one user using Sign Up Sign In user flow, that is created as **local account** with email address in  <kbd>**identities**</kbd> property like this:

[image]

When I ran your query to **filter** users by email from `identities` and some other property using MS graph API, I too got **same error**:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=identities/any(id:id/issuer+eq+'yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com'+and+id/issuerAssignedId+eq+'user@email.com')+and+creationType+eq+'LocalAccount'
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Alternatively, you can use any coding language to **customize** the response of all users list by applying **filtering** locally.

In my case, I used below Microsoft Graph PowerShell script and got the response with **filtered user** successfully like this:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scope "User.Read.All" -TenantId "b2c_tenant_id" 
$allUsers = Get-MgUser -Property "id,displayName,identities,mail,creationType"
$emailToFilter = "user@email.com"

$filteredUsers = $allUsers | Where-Object {
    ($_.Identities -ne $null -and $_.Identities.signInType -eq 'emailAddress' -and $_.Identities.issuerAssignedId -eq $emailToFilter) -and
    $_.CreationType -eq 'LocalAccount'
}

$filteredUsers | Select-Object id, displayName, @{Name="Identities";Expression={$_.Identities | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 -Compress}}
```

**Response:**

[image]

AFAIK, forcing the **user flow** to store the email in the `mail` property is not possible. As a workaround, you can create one **extension attribute** to store email address while registering via Sign Up and Sign In flow.

**UPDATE:**

I created one **custom** attribute named **`email`**  in my B2C tenant like this:

[image]

Before running Sign Up and Sign In user flow, make sure to select **`email`** attribute:

[image]

When user registers using Sign Up and Sign In user flow, it will ask to enter **`email`** again for custom attribute like this:

[image]

You can find that **custom attribute** in token claims after user creation in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website:

[image]

Now, you can search the users by filtering with [**extension_b2cappId_email**](https://i.imgur.com/VR93BEx.png) value and some other user property like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=extension_<>_email+eq+'user@email.com'+and+creationType+eq+'LocalAccount'+&$select=displayName,+extension_<>_email,creationType,id
```

**Response:**
[image]

Comment: Custom policies won't help. "mail" is not a supported attribute. You'll need to use an extension attribute.

Comment: @rbrayb Thanks for the confirmation, updated the answer